# Converting a stored Procedure into a user defined Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying to convert a procedure into function that chooses n parameters from a table and for each n, chooses k column names from another table. it finally has to create a table with some fixed columns + n*k columns which change with input parameters. k is also different for each n. I wrote the procedure using a dynamically created query.

For the function, I figured I could run a cursor or while loop to fetch each n and feed the corresponding column names into a table variable. declaring the variables and setting their values inside the loop felt like the efficient way to go.

Finally I'll pivot the variables and join them to form the required table.
The problem lies therein. Declaring, or even if I already declared them, then calling the table variables in the loop sequentially to assign them.

```
{
Declare @plan_section table (
    Roll identity (1,1)
    Plan_id int
    Plan_section_id int
)

Insert into @plan_section
Select plan_id, plan_section_id from t_plan_section where plan_id=@plan_id

Declare @n int, @plan_count int
Set @n =1
Set @plan_count = (select count(plan_section_id) from t_plan_section where plan_id = @plan_id)

While @n<@plan_count
Begin

Declare  Variable_’+cast(@n, varchar(2))+’       table ( ‘@plan_section_name’ varchar(100) )
Insert into     variable_’+@n+’
Select metric from t_plan_section_metric a join @plan_section b using(plan_section_id) where b.roll = @n

set @n = @n+1

End
}
```

here's a query snippet i used but didn't work.

Please consider that there are n plan section corresponding to each plan_id, and k column names being retrieved into n table variables declared within the loop.
Any and all suggestions are welcomed. if you have another approach, by all means do share.

Comment: Please consider adding some examples of what you have.

Comment: using function we cannot create tables or temp tables , it only supports table variables.

Comment: I am only using table variables.

Comment: *"It didn't work"* doesn't cut it. In what way does it not work? AFAICT you can't have a dynamic number of columns in a TABLE variable returned from a function.

Comment: it says " syntax error near '+' "   where I am declaring the variable. And a lot of subsequent crap.

Comment: `Declare global    Variable_’+@n` > you can't declare variables this way. What's the `global` doing in there anyway. Also `@n = @n+1`... that should be `SET @n = @n+1`.

Comment: Can you please suggest a way in which I can declare, or just call different variables in each cycle of the loop to set them to a value? I am new to sql, and relatively unknown to its syntax rules.

Comment: GLOBAL was supposed to set the scope of the variable, as I have to use it outside of the loop. As per your opposition, I have removed it.

Comment: First: if you want to message someone in particular, start your comment with `@user_name`. For example `@TT.` if you want to message me. Second: You can `DECLARE` the variable outside the loop if you want to use it in the scope of the function. Third: you cannot `DECLARE` variables dyamically (at least I think that's what you are trying to do). Variables need to have a static name, unless you make the whole inside of the function dynamic. I would advise against that. Last: you can't declare a `FUNCTION` to return a dynamic `TABLE` (ie having a variable definition).